# Characterizing polynomials whose associated semi-algebraic set is bounded?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hello,

I'm a theoretical computer scientist, and would be interested by the following problem: given a polynomial p, over R, multi-variate, is there a sufficient condition on its parameters such that {$x~ | ~p(x)\leq 0$} is bounded?

The idea would be to somewhat generalize the fact that given a semi-definite matrix positive P, the set {$x ~|~ (1,~ x^t~ ;~ x~ P)\text{ is sdp}$} describes an ellipsoid, potentially flat in some dimensions.

The problem seems to be too easily formulated for having not been deeply considered by mathematicians, but I did not manage to find any reference.

Any help and/or pointers would be appreciated.

Best,
Yannick.

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit open-ended because I could give you sufficient and very restrictive conditions for this to happen. Here are a couple of elementary remarks that might help.

Let $[p]$ denote the top degree  part of $p$.   This is a homogeneous polynomial of  degree $k$. If you require that $[p](u)>0$ for any $u\in \mathbb{R}^n$ of length $1$ then you get the desired conclusion. Note that this forces the degree  $k$ to be even.  This reduces   the problem to characterizing  even degree homogeneous polynomial which are positive definite. There are many of those, but I don't know how to characterize them. Here is a large  supply. Suppose that $Q(y_1,\dotsc, y_m)$ is a nontrivial  homogeneous polynomial with  nonnegative coefficients, and $q_1,\dotsc, q_m$ are positive definite  quadratic forms in $n$ variables $x_1,\dotsc, x_n$. Then  $Q(q_1,\dotsc, q_m)$ is a positive definite  homogeneous polynomial in the variables $x_1,\dotsc, x_n$.

The minimum value  of a polynomial $P$ of  even degree $k$ on the unit sphere is obtained via Lagrange multipliers. Look at the solutions of the system

$$ \lambda\in\mathbb{R},\;\;u\in\mathbb{R}^n,\;\;|u|=1,\;\;  \nabla P(u)=\lambda u. \tag{1}$$

The Euler identity for   homogeneous functions implies

$$ k P(u)= u\cdot \nabla P(u) =\lambda |u|^2 =\lambda. $$

The polynomial  $P$ will be positive definite  if the system (1)  has no solutions $(\lambda, u)$  with $\lambda\leq 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I need to think a bit more on it, it's quite hard for me to link it with my computer science consideration. But you definitively gave me things to think about, so thanks.

I would also like to precise a bit my question, as I do realize I should have been more specific, as you pointed out. But it will be in my next comment, the limit of characters being quite restrictive. :)

Comment: I do want to have a necessary condition on p such that $I_p$={$x~|~p(x)\leq 0$} is bounded, but I also want it to be not too restrictive such that a wild broad of non-empty interior $I_p$ are elligible.
Intuitively, I would really like to identify an extension, on degree 4 for instance, of ellipsoids. For instance, {$x~|~x^4+y^4-x^2-y^2+0.5\leq 0$} would be of interest on one of my specific exemples.
And finally, I need to be able to formulate it as a Linear Matrix Inequality, as it will be a constraint added in a semidefinite programming problem.
Any additionnal thoughts are welcome, 
Thanks.

Comment: The example you wrote  is bounded since the top degree part $x^4+y^4$ is  positive definite.

Comment: I therefore definitively must go for some experiments with this condition. My concern would then to see how to avoid empty set, but I might tweak something with the objective function. Thanks again!


Would you know of, by any chance, a reference I could read to see the theory/background of this result?

Comment: This book http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/marie-francoise.roy/bpr-ed2-posted1.html  seems to be the right   place to look. One of the authors, Basu, is interested in  computer science applications as well.

Comment: Ahah thank you a lot, I wasn't aware of this book, but Mrs. Roy is working less than 500 meters from me, quite funny I get redirected to her through someone working in the US :) I take a look at it! Thanks once more.

Comment: The world is  smaller than we think.